# Компиляция программы

Tags: c++, c++builder, микроконтроллеры

Есть исходник программы управления устройством через USB (микроконтроллер Attiny45).

Сначала пробовал через 6-й С++ Builder, потом через RAD Studio Xe, так поставил Jedi code lib.

Под рад студию он благо нормально встал. НО, первое с чем столкнулся в Rad, это то что он

- не находит статические библиотеки icsbcb60.lib, JvStdCtrlsC6R.lib, JvCustomC6R.lib, JvSystemC6R.lib, JvCoreC6R.lib (может это косяк версий),
- но основное это то что он не находит компоненты JvHidControllerClass и JvComponentBase (.hpp) которые по идее должны быть в Jedi.

Вопрос, куда прописывать пути для установки библиотек Jedi, и что делать с теми библиотеками, которых нигде нет?

Comment: Library path ?

Answer (score 2):

Можно взглянуть на исходники? И хотелось бы понять с чем связан выбор RAD Studio XE? Если необходимо работать с USB на ПК я бы посоветовал начать изучение С#? тем более Вы говорите, что новичок в Си++. А так напишите что должна выполнять Ваша программа? Но судя по тому что у Вас AtTiny45 то Вы будете реализовывать hid девайс. Поэтому в качестве самой оптимальной библиотеки посоветую V-USB: http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html

А теперь попытаюсь показать реализацию такого рода ПО:
Подключаем Все необходимое, в том числе библиотеку V-USB.

```
namespace MyUSB {
public partial class izuchaem_usb : Form {
int smplcnt = 0;
     public usbscope()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.usb.ProductId = 0x0002;
                this.usb.VendorId = 0x4242;
            }
    //Проверка наличия связи, но не забудьте на схем если проц интеловский пуловский резистор 1.5 кОм, если АМД то 2.2кОм
            private void usb_OnDeviceArrived(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               Label1.Text  = "Ваше устройство подключено!";
            }

            private void usb_OnDeviceRemoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Invoke(new EventHandler(usb_OnDeviceRemoved), new object[] { sender, e });
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Ваше устройство отключено!";
                }
            }

            private void usb_OnSpecifiedDeviceArrived(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Найдено HID устройство";
            }

            private void usb_OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Invoke(new EventHandler(usb_OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved), new object[] { sender, e });
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "HID устройство отключено";
                }
            }

            protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnHandleCreated(e);
                usb.RegisterHandle(Handle);
            }

            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            {
                usb.ParseMessages(ref m);
                base.WndProc(ref m);    // Вводим сообшение на основной форме
            }

            private void usb_OnDataRecieved(object sender, DataRecievedEventArgs args)
            {

                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Invoke(new DataRecievedEventHandler(usb_OnDataRecieved), new object[] { sender, args });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                    if(!paused){
                        //Получаем данные с устройства
                        int val1 = (int)args.data[1]
                        smplcnt++;

                        display(val1);
                }
            }
}
}
```

Как то так. Мой большой совет копать в сторону микроконтроллеров с аппаратным USB, так как по личному опыту знаю, что ничего путного из программного HID USB 1.1 не выжать, но для радиолюбительских конструкций самое то! Желаю удачи в изучении МК - это ну очень увлекательно!)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6mnlX2M5DFkOW8tNnRka2EwUk0/edit?usp=sharing   в архиве исходники, в данном варианте программа управляет устройством, которое  просто включает, выключает нагрузку (220v), я хотел попробовать ее изменить что б включение происходило с задержкой, где-то около 20 мин для начала, после включения работало еще минут 10-15 и потом выключалось, но так и не смог просто скомпилить файлы(. Просто было относительно готовое устройство никто не парился, вот сейчас приспичило, я бы и сам рад собрать и прошить что-то подобное (как раз жду пару МК) но времени нет(.

Comment: Так в Visual Studio 6 в 1. Скачать не могу Ваши исходники, какие то видимо проблемы с интернетом у меня! Посмотрите еще вот эту статейку, по Вашему вопросу здесь максимально полный ответ, не в плане компиляции, а в плане управления различными нагрузками через USB. И еще вопрос: что вы используете в качестве силового ключа?

Comment: Открыл! Тут кода на 2 странички. Попробуйте сразу перевести его в VC++. Лучше сразу начинать с того на чем будет удобнее в дальнейшем работать! А компилятор под МК какой?

Comment: Компилятора под МК нет ( В качестве ключа - реле с 6v входящим и 220v на 12А выходным, короче, на пару ватт потянет, больше и не надо. Боюсь перевод я не осилю, я открывал в VS Но ни к чему путному это не привело, сейчас открыты unit.h, unit.cpp, и mp709_example.cpp

Comment: В качестве компилятора я посоветую CodeVisionAVR, писать надо на чистом Си. Готов Вам помочь, но только после работы. Сложностей не должно быть, а помочь товарищам радиолюбителям - святое дело!

Comment: Ааа, пардон)) CVAVR стоит)) единственное я МК не подберусь, жало не то и что обиднее всего, Com порта нет( А от помощи я б не отказался... Велика вероятность что придется перепрошивать?

Создал проект в VS закинул файлы исходники... после отладки выдал 50 ошибок)

Comment: Если нет ComPorta то копайте в сторону преобразователя FT232RL, это преобразователь UART-USB, работаете так же как с интерфейсом RS-232, а передача идет по USB, для первых поделок вполне хорошая микруха. Я в ближайшее время в графе исследования постараюсь привести пример работоспособный организации такого процесса!